# Read csv with pyspark, issue with backslash (\) before quote field last quote

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, databricks

I have a csv with the following content:

```
DoctorName, Description, Salary
"Dr. Jason BAH\","",138.42200000000000000000
"Dr. \"Sleep\" MAH","",200.42200000000000000000
```

However, when I try to read it and transform it to a csv (using: `option("quote", '"').option("multiline", True).option("header", True).option("escape", "\\")`), I got the following:

| DoctorName | Description | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dr. Jason BAH"," | 138.422 | null |
| Dr. "Sleep" MAH | null | 200.422 |

How can I read the csv and obtain the following dataframe:

| DoctorName | Description | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dr. Jason BAH | null | 138.422 |
| Dr. "Sleep" MAH | null | 200.422 |

Basically the issue is that the backslash in the end of the first column (right before the last double quote) is being inferred as a escape character instead of a usual backslash.
However, when I import this csv to Excel it works fine.

Aren't the escape character and quote the correct ones? Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is just improperly encoded data. There's no way for the parser to know that `\"` is really supposed to be `"` in the first row, unlike the second row where literal double quotes are wanted.

Comment: What does Excel actually show? Because I seriously doubt it's `Dr. Jason BAH`. Either you disable escaping and get `Dr. Jason BAH\` or you enable it and get the current results. You can't have different behavior on each row

Comment: (I'm not sure it's correct to say that Excel is *right*, only that whatever heuristic it might be using doesn't get tripped up by your actual data.)

Comment: @chepner it doesn't. Excel reads the first value as `Dr. Jason BAH\`

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in Excel, nor did I expect to.  CSV isn't an Excel format. Excel can be registered to load CSV files though. When you double-click on a CSV file Excel will load it using the current locale's defaults for date, field and decimal separators. It won't change the way it's working from one row to the other either. If you want to change the defaults you'll have to go to `Data` then `From Text File/CSV`

Comment: The correct option here is to fix the code that produced `"Dr. Jason BAH\"`. Otherwise you'll have to write your own flat text parser that handles such discrepancies. I don't say CSV parser because that's no longer a CSV file